# Custom error page for configuration error in Play framework

Tags: java, configuration, playframework-2.0

When my Play 2.0.4 application is running but my database is down, Play will show visitors a default `Configuration error - Cannot connect to database`-page.

Besides the problem that this prints out half of my `application.conf` for everyone to see, I would like to display a more userfriendly error page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Configuration file

That error page is only show when running Play in dev mode (ie with `play run`). When using Play in production mode(ie `play start`), it should show a 500-internal server error.

Checkout [the official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production) to see how to start your application in Prod mode.

#### Error pages

About customization of the error page, you will have to check out the [Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaGlobal) which allows you to do that kind of things.